# Access to MainViewModel from Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm very new to Caliburn Micro and would like to access ViewModel properties during OnExit.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mainViewModel.MyParam == 42)
        {

        }
        base.OnExit(sender, e);
    }
```

From the default WP7 template (without Caliburn) i'm used to have App.ViewModel, which is a static field with a singleton get accessor, where the viewmodel will be created on the first access.
(See next code snippet)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();

            return viewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            viewModel = value;
        }
    }
```

Now i try to use Caliburn Micro 1.1 with a WPF project and don't know how this should be done.
I need access to the ViewModel during OnExit inside AppBootStrapper.

I assume, that this should be possible, because my AppBootstrapper is inherited from Bootstrapper, but can't find the right way of doing this..

Any hints, how this can be done in WPF are very welcome?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: I'm assuming Caliburn.Micro because you mention WP7 (if not, please correct). What version of the framework?

Comment: And how did you do it in WP7? In `App.ViewModel`, what is `App`?

Comment: Hi Joel, sorry for not being exact in my question. With WP7 i used the default template. My question is based on WPF version of CM 1.1. Just updated my question! Thx!

Comment: Also consider adding some other Tags:
Caliburn.Micro, C#

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MainViewModel mainViewModel = IoC.Get<MainViewModel>();
```

Here is how it would look in your code:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the Main View Model
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = IoC.Get<MainViewModel>();
        if (mainViewModel.MyParam == 42)
        {
            //Do work
        }
        base.OnExit(sender, e);
    }
}
```

This assumes Two Things:

1. Your MainViewModel class is exporting typeof(MainViewModel) and not something different, like typeof(IShell)
2. You are using the default MEF implementation of C.M.

Comment: Yes, you're assumptions are absolutely right, although i didn't know this before. With your tip i'm able to get to the MainViewmodel, but now it always creates a new instance. What pattern should i use to get always the one and only instance of my viewmodel. Do i have to implement some singleton pattern myself, or can cm help me also here?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: IoC shoud only create a new instance once, and then send you copies of that same instance on further request for the MainViewModel.

Question - do you manually intanciate your MainViewModel, or do you let Caliburn.Micro do it for you?

Essentially, the IoC static class should be handling the same thing you are using your singleton Container for, but it's a lot "heavier" than the Container solution in that link. Glad to helP!

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little bit more i think i've found the solution to my own question: Added SimpleContainer.cs from here: [link](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimpleContainer)

and added this to my AppBootstrapper code:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainViewModel>
{

  private SimpleContainer container;

  protected override void Configure()
  {
    container = new SimpleContainer();
    container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(MainViewModel), null, typeof(MainViewModel));
    container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IWindowManager), null, typeof(WindowManager));
  }

  protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
  {
    return container.GetInstance(service, key);
  }
```

Would be great to hear some comment, whether this is ok or not.